# How to add 0 (zero) for mobile number

Tags: mysql, database

On the `mobile` field I have a list of mobile number starting with 7xxxxxxxxx

I need a quick way to add 0 at the beginning, eg: 07xxxxxxx

But it will need to check if 0 exist or not before updating

Is it possible to do that by SQL query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET mobile = CONCAT('0', mobile)
WHERE mobile NOT LIKE '0%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE the_table
    SET the_phone_number = '0'||the_phone_number
WHERE the_phone_number NOT LIKE '0%'
```

This assumes that MySQL is configured with ANSI mode (because of the standard concatenation operator `||`)

Comment: Are you running MySQL in ANSI mode? Otherwise I think `||` is the logical `OR` operator. But as I always use ANSI mode, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

let's say the mobile field is a 9 digits (including the leading zero),
here is an example :-

```
mysql> select lpad('123456789', 9, 0);
+-------------------------+
| lpad('123456789', 9, 0) |
+-------------------------+
| 123456789               | 
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select lpad('12345678', 9, 0);
+------------------------+
| lpad('12345678', 9, 0) |
+------------------------+
| 012345678              | 
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```